# How to make UUID field default when there's already ID field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a project and problem is I've already created models with simple ID column but now my requirements are changed and I want to replace ID field (model) with UUID field I just updated my model:

```
uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

but when I run my migrations I got an error

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1829, "Cannot drop column 'id':
>   needed in a foreign key constraint

Please guide me how can I perform this migration?

Comment: any place you have used this model as a foreign relation?

Comment: Yes, I've used it

Comment: then you have remove it first, makemigrations, then change this model with uuid migrate and then use it in the other model and then migrate again

Comment: Can you share some code snippet? It would be convenient for me !

Comment: there is no code for this, its just following the steps, the one i told earlier

Comment: Oh I see, Well Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 33):

here are the list of actions that you need to do

1 - add the new `uuid` field to model (I name this model `Base`) then generate migration files

> uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, blank=True, null=True)

- note that uuid is not primarykey yet
- note that `blank = null =True`

2- in this step you should populate `uuid` field with valid data. you should write a data migration file for `Base` model. please check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) for more info

your forwards method should be something like this:

```
for item in Base.objects.all():
    item.uuid = uuid4()
    item.save()
```

3- change uuid field to this and generate migrations

> uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, unique=True)

- note that uuid is not primarykey yet, but it's unique now

4 - for other models which are pointing to `Base` model you should add a new foreignkey pointing to uuid field

assumig your default relation to Base model is something like this

```
base = models.ForeignKey(
    Base, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='base'
)
```

you should add a temprory field like this

```
base_uuid = models.ForeignKey(
    Base,
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    related_name='base_uuid',
    to_field='uuid',
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
```

- note that I have explicitly defined `to_field` which tell django this foreign key is not pointing to default `pk` field
- you should keep old foreign key field
- also set `blank = null = True`
- for all foreignkeys/manytomanyfield pointing to `Base` you should add this temp field

5- in this step you should create a data migration file,

in this data migration file you need to fill all `base_uuid` fields with valid data (based on old `base` field) your migration code can be something like this

```
for item in RelatedModel.objects.all():
    item.base_uuid_id = item.base.uuid
```

- after this step all `base_uuid` fields in all models should contain a valid data

6- in all related models drop related field (keep the new `base_uuid` field but discard old related field) and generate a migration file

7- delete the db_constraint on all FK fields - this is needed, because django will connect through the unique constraint from `base_uuid` which will be dropped if we change `uuid` to pk.

```py
base_uuid = models.ForeignKey(
    Base,
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    related_name='base_uuid',
    to_field='uuid',
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    db_constraint=False
)
```

8- in `Base` model change uuid field and generate a migration file

> uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, primary_key=True)

- uuid is now a primary key!

9- in all related models (models which you have added `base_uuid` fields) update the field

- rename field name (remove `_uuid` from column name) (make this a **individual Migration**!)
- change `relate_name` field name (remove `_uuid` from related name)
- remove `blank = null = true` if necessary
- remove `to_field='uuid'` argument (you don't need that any more)

**Very Important Note:** run these code with test data and create a full backup from your database before running this code on your actual data

Comment: Great answer @aliva, however, I have an error at step 7 : django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type uuid to integer. I am sure I did all the steps correctly. What am I missing? Do you know how to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment to the answer by @aliva. I believe there is an error with step 5.

```
for item in RelatedModel.objects.all():
item.base_uuid_id = item.base
```

drop the .uuid from item.base

I was getting an error Cannot assign "UUID('...')" must be a "Base" instance.

Comment: You can Suggest An Edit, instead of posting a Comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively simple solution, but **use this only if you can afford to delete the whole data in the DB currently** (you may have just started the project).

Reset the migrations

- Delete all the migrations in the migrations folder except the **init**.py file.
- Run `python manage.py makemigrations`
- Run `python manage.py migrate`

This will create entirely new migrations for your application, and you won't face any type issues in this case as the type of the uuid field gets set in the initial migration field itself.