# "cannot cast type bigint to uuid" while changing db from sqLite3 to PostgressSql

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, django-models, uuid

So here is my Pet model and PetAttachmentImage model as well, in case if it can give any extra info.
The problem is that I created my whole backend on Django using default engine (sqlite3) and now I need to deploy it on a cloud, in my case its neonDb - which uses postgres as engine.

When I'm trying to migrate my data from sqlite3 on my local storage to postgress on neonDb I get this error - [psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type bigint to uuid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idpsx.jpg)

So I've done my research and found similar problem even here on StackOverflow,[however it's solution doesn't work in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64319543/cannot-cast-type-integer-to-uuid), and I don't understand why. Also I use uuid as my primary key, I created id only to make it explicit about the fact that I don't want to use it, and to alter it with my custom one if it's somehow still exists by default.

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="Unnamed")
    animal = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='images/pet.png', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    info = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.animal} - {self.name} - {self.breed}"

class PetAttachmentImage(models.Model):
    pet = models.ForeignKey(Pet, to_field='uuid', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="pet")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/pet_attachments_images/', blank=False, null=False)
```

As I understood, the problem is that postgres engine uses bigInt type for id by default, and it can't convert it to uuid. But the thing is - I'm not even trying to convert it and I don't need it. As I mentioned above, I created "id" column just to alter default one, that is created implicitly everytime you create a model.

So why do I get this error still and how to solve it?

Comment: The class you show here is all fine, the issue is an alter table statement that you execute. That will not work, not in PostgreSQL, not in any other database. And PostgreSQL doesn't use a BIGINT by default of an id, there is no default for an id. So where does your alter table statement come from?

Comment: You mean that the problem can be with some old migrations/cache in my django project? Because I'm not doing explicitly any alter statements at the moment of migration on postgress, it's happening automatically. Because if I execute "makemigrations" right before running migrate - it says "no changes detected", and then I use "migrate" and get the error