# Django and Postgres: psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: could not create unique index "main_customuser_pkey" DETAIL: Key (token)=(Key) is duplicated

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

this error show up when i migrate to db using `python manage.py migrate`, model:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=322,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=320,unique=True)
    token = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid1,editable=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD ='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

Comment: You have duplicate values for `token` present in your database already. You have to update those entries so they are unique / delete them.

Comment: token field is newly added (hence why i am migrating to db), i am not sure what kind of duplicate i would get if it is newly added, would you please give some explanation and code ?@AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: Ah, I see, the problem is that you are adding this new field and you are specifying it to be unique (primary key) Django calls the function specified for `default` _once_ and tries to specify that value for _all_ objects in the database given that this must be unique it naturally fails.

Comment: and what would be the solution for default?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make UUID field default when there's already ID field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200026/how-to-make-uuid-field-default-when-theres-already-id-field)

Comment: nope. it does not.